# Задание массива из таблицы. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Всем привет. Я разрабатываю страничку и у меня возникает несколько проблем. Первая и самая важная, когда я пытаюсь вызвать последнее API MoveProperty у меня вылетает 400 ошибка. Это вызвано тем что вместо одного из параметров я передаю пустой массив.

```
const handleMoveAccount = () => {
    const request = {
      sourceClientId: clientID,
      propertyId: propertyID,
      destinationClientId: destinationClient,
      useExistingSources: existingSources,
      useExistingMerchantAccounts: existingMerchantAccounts,
      accountIds: selectedAccountsToMove.accountId,    // here set empty array[]
    };
    console.log(clientID, propertyID, destinationClient);
    console.log(selectedAccountsToMove);
    moveProperty(request);
  };
```

У меня вопрос следующего рода, в чем я ошибся при создании массива? Как я понимаю в этот массив должна была записываться вторая таблица и там бы я уже передавал этот **selectedAccountsToMove.accountId**.
My code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Spin, Select, Button, Form, notification, Checkbox, Typography } from 'antd';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useFetch, usePromise } from 'XXX';
import * as apiService from 'services/ApiService';
import AccountTypesV2 from 'components/AccountTypesV2';
import AccountsV2 from 'components/AccountsV2';
import { LAYOUT, TAIL_LAYOUT } from 'constants/layouts';
import { useQueryParams } from 'hooks/useQueryParams';
import styles from './MovePropertyV2.scss';

const MovePropertyV2 = () => {
  const [clientID, propertyID] = useQueryParams();
  const onFail = (error) => notification.error({ message: error });
  const onSuccess = (response) => {
    if (response[0].includes('Exception')) {
      notification.error({ message: response });
    } else {
      notification.success({ message: response });
    }
  };

  const [{ isLoading: IsMoveProperty }, moveProperty] = usePromise(apiService.moveProperty, { onFail, onSuccess });
  const [clients, isClientLoading] = useFetch(apiService.getAllActiveClents);
  // const handleFormFinish = (formValue) => console.log(formValue);

  /* const [{ data: accounts, isLoading }, fetchAccounts, clientsId] = usePromise(
    apiService.getAccountsByAccountTypes, { onFail, onSuccess }
  ); */
  const [{ data: accounts, isLoading }, fetchAccounts] = usePromise(
    apiService.getAccountsByAccountTypes, { onFail, onSuccess }
  );

  const [selectedAccountTypes, setSelectedItems] = useState([]);
  const [selectedAccountsToMove, setSelectedAccountsToMove] = useState([]);
  console.log(selectedAccountTypes);
  console.log(selectedAccountsToMove);
  const [destinationClient, setDestinationClient] = useState();
  const [existingSources, setExistingSources] = useState(false);
  const [existingMerchantAccounts, setExistingMerchantAccounts] = useState(false);

  const handleMoveAccount = () => {
    const request = {
      sourceClientId: clientID,
      propertyId: propertyID,
      destinationClientId: destinationClient,
      useExistingSources: existingSources,
      useExistingMerchantAccounts: existingMerchantAccounts,
      accountIds: selectedAccountsToMove.accountId,
    };
    console.log(clientID, propertyID, destinationClient);
    console.log(selectedAccountsToMove);
    moveProperty(request);
  };

  // console.log(clientId, selectedAccountTypes);
  const accountSearch = () => {
    const requestData = {
      clientId: parseInt(clientID, 10),
      accountTypes: selectedAccountTypes,
    };
    fetchAccounts(requestData);
  };

  return (
    <Spin spinning={isLoading}>
      <Typography.Title>Move Property</Typography.Title>
      <Form {...LAYOUT} onFinish={IsMoveProperty}>
        <Form.Item {...TAIL_LAYOUT}>
          <Select
            placeholder="Destination Client Name"
            onChange={setDestinationClient}
            loading={isClientLoading}
          >
            {clients.map((client) => (
              <Select.Option key={client.id} value={client.id}>
                {client.name}
              </Select.Option>
            ))}
          </Select>
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item {...TAIL_LAYOUT}>
          <Checkbox onChange={setExistingSources}>Use existing Source</Checkbox>
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item {...TAIL_LAYOUT}>
          <Checkbox onChange={setExistingMerchantAccounts}>Use existing merchant accounts</Checkbox>
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item {...TAIL_LAYOUT}>
          <AccountTypesV2 onSelectingItems={setSelectedItems} />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item {...TAIL_LAYOUT}>
          <Button htmlType="submit" onClick={accountSearch} className={styles.submitButton}>Search Account</Button>
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item {...TAIL_LAYOUT}>
          {accounts
          && <AccountsV2 accounts={accounts} onSelectingAccountsItems={setSelectedAccountsToMove} />}
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item {...TAIL_LAYOUT}>
          <Button htmlType="submit" onClick={handleMoveAccount} className={styles.submitButton}>Move Property</Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </Spin>
  );
};

MovePropertyV2.propTypes = {
  accountId: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({})),
  onSelectingItems: PropTypes.func,
};

MovePropertyV2.defaultProps = {
  accountId: [],
  onSelectingItems: () => { },
};

export default MovePropertyV2;
```

Помимо этого у меня вылетает такая ошибка:
[image: SomeError]

Comment: const [selectedAccountsToMove, setSelectedAccountsToMove] = useState([]); у вас state инициируется пустым массивом, а метод изменения спрятан в <AccountsV2/> компонент

Comment: Спасибо, да, я нашел ошибку. А можете подсказать что за ошибка на скрине?

Comment: ну он пытался отрендерить массив объектов в качестве дочерних элементов, но массив оказался не массивом